# Saving a pytoch tensor as a 32-bit grayscale Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, pytorch, save-image

I have manipulated a 32-bit grayscale `.tif` image which I converted to tensor using PIL. After this I saved it with:

```
torchvision.utils.save_image(train_img_poac,fp=str(j)+".tif")
```

This method automatically converts the tensor to an RGB format image. I want my output image to be a 32-bit grayscale image.

I tried to use the arguments in the `save_image` function but could not find anything. Is converting it to numpy ndarray and then converting it to a 32-bit Image an option?

Comment: Try `tifffile` maybe... https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `save_image` doesn't have an option for preserving one-channel images. You can use a [different library](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/save-one-channel-normalized-tensor-to-image/38402) like OpenCV:

```py
import cv2

image = train_img_poac.numpy()
cv2.imwrite('image_name', image)
```